# Only in Chrome, bullet showing for top item in OL even though list-style-type:none

Tags: css, list, google-chrome, styles, html-lists

I've tried a million ways to figure out why this bullet point won't go away. It's just for the top item and only shows in Chrome.  Anyone able to see what's going on?

```
http://162.242.228.47/?page_id=6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Chrome is indeed acting weird, but the reason is probably due to invalid markup in your HTML, specifically this:

```
<li id="dc_jqaccordion_widget-2" class="widget-container">
```

W3 Markup Validator results in:

```
Line 136, Column 59:
Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context.
```

Your `li` must be contained within `ul` / `ol` / `menu` ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html)).

If you insist on CSS solution only and reluctant to change your HTML, just add `list-style: none;` to `dc_jqaccordion_widget-2` as well.

Also, you seem to have some additional serious validation errors (duplicate `</head>` for example), see [W3 Validator Results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://162.242.228.47/?page_id=6&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: It's all code that came with the accordion menu plugin, I'll try adjusting the jqaccordion with list style non as well.  Thanks!